# How to set separate html tables

Tags: html, css

I have html tables and I would like to add summary columns next to it.
I could create simple table, but I couldn't figure out how to set separate tables next to it.

My desired result is described below. If someone has idea, please let me know.

[image]

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding:5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding:5px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.noborder {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Rather than creating another table I will suggest to use the no-border cell.

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement, you actually do not need another table, but in future if you want to use table side by side then you can use below solution.

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding:5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="margin-left:20px">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```